# Which classification algorithms to use with nominal data?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, classification, multiclass-classification

I  work with a dataset which stores business tasks and for each it mainly keeps track of some nominal data such as the Department, Employee assigned, Product, etc.
Past completed task have a completion time.

My goal is, based on the completion time of past tasks, to be able to predict the completion time of a newly arrived task based on its attributes (Department, Employee assigned, Product, etc).

Given that basically all of the attributes of a task are nominal and will be encoded/one-hot-encoded, which would be the best algorithm to use in this case.

Comment: it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro & **NOTE** in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Comment: How come this question is related with `regression`, `classification` and `multiclass-classification`? The question is related with ml-algorithm suggestion.

Comment: @desertnaut Sorry about that, still understanding the whole dynamic in here, should've read better the help center. Thank you for pointing that out.